# Linguistic meaning among evolved artificial agents

Tags: artificial-intelligence, social-epistemology, semiotics

Suppose we have used an evolutionary algorithm to produce a community of artificial agents. These agents navigate a virtual environment, seeking food and avoiding predators. No one designed these agents intentionally; humans set up the virtual environment and the selection criteria (find food, don't get eaten, reproduce), and the evolutionary algorithm designed the details.

Furthermore suppose the agents have evolved enough to send each other signals, which may influence each other's behavior. There may be signals about where the food is or where the enemies are, or even signals negotiating agreements about who takes what food. Or other types of signals. There is no limit on what type of signals the agents may send each other or how the signals may be interpreted, and no human has designed any of these signals manually; the evolutionary algorithm produced them.

It is not necessary to say that these agents are in any way intelligent. The situation I've described is not in any way farfetched or science fiction. Situations like those I describe have been studied, such as [here](https://ijcopi.org/ojs/article/view/203).

Now, the broad philosophical question is: *is there a general way for us as outside observers to determine what a particular signal sent from one agent to another *means* or whether it is true or false?*

For example, one agent comes near food, tells other agents "40433," and agents that receive the message flock towards that agent's position. Observing this, we might imagine that "40433" means something like, "there's food here." But could "40433" mean instead just "come to me"? How do we support a particular interpretation of the meaning of the message? And if agent #25 uses the 40433 message when being chased by a predator, and other agents approach agent #25 and get eaten by the predator, which results in agent #25 escaping the predator, can we say that agent #25 was lying or telling a falsehood? Or was #25 simply telling others to approach, with no falsehood?

Comment: I do not think  "broad philosophical questions" are suitable for SE, there are encyclopedia entries for that. Questions here should be narrow: who said X about Y, what did A say about Y, etc. The last paragraph of the post is material for discussion forums. There is also vast literature on ["radical translation" and "radical interpretation"](https://iep.utm.edu/indeterm/) going back to Quine and Davidson, indeterminacy of distinguishing between rabbits and undetached rabbit parts, global interpretational constraints, etc.

Comment: @Conifold I don't think it's too broad, because I have a specific answer in mind. Specifically I would say that first we must impute *objectives* onto the agents, so that we interpret them as trying to achieve some goal as best they can (e.g. maximize reproductive fitness). Then we can look at how certain messages and mental states help or hinder them in achieving the objectives, under the principle that falsehoods sometimes cause suboptimal actions towards the objective. The meaning of a message can be understood as those circumstances in which it is true (i.e. leads towards optimal actions).

Comment: If you have an answer then why ask? And you are not the only one with an answer, others have ten more. We can't review all of that and disputes over it, that's why it's too broad.

Comment: @Conifold I ask to see if others also have answers that may be different from mine and worth considering.

Comment: And that sort of thing is for discussion forums and off-topic here. Questions with one definitive answer based on published literature are expected, not exploratory discussion prompts.

Comment: @Conifold Most of the questions on this site could be answered in multiple possible ways. That's the nature of philosophy.

Comment: "meaning" is a very very complex issue, usually linked with mind, intentionality, understanding,... Two server exchanging messages through a network are they communicating? are they understanding the meaning of the messages exchanged?

Comment: Is this how Quine and Wittgenstein might say language is behavioral? Behavioral implies observable

Comment: The restriction of being an *outside* observer may not be interesting here. Your question is more simply: Is there is a way of determining the meaning of a signal without a prior means of communication? And the answer is basically yes, as explained in the literature (in AI, and philosophy) on signaling games (initiated by David Lewis).  How this might "answer" Quinean worries about the indeterminacy of translation or truth by convention doesn't yet (to my knowledge) have a definitive treatment, but e.g. Skyrms does at least mention the issues is his book "The Stag Hunt...".

Comment: I'm putting the dagger in this one as unfocused. It's an interesting question, but you might want to narrow down your question. What you're talking about is vaguely at least three marmalades (translation problem, signals intelligence, and theories of semantics) smeared across one piece of toast.

Comment: It's a provocative question, but it's really, really broad. I would say that if you are talking about artificial life and artificial intelligence scenarios, the behavior of agents would always be understood in relation to the norms encoded into the agent. Computational intelligence generally relies on encoding certain weights into decision making processes when developing goal-oriented software. In this way, by look at the behavior and the values, the "meaning" of the communication will be rather clear. True problems with understanding semantics would require AGI, and that is...

Comment: more of in the neighborhood of metaphysical speculation than experimental philosophy at this point.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the situation is entirely analogous to *our* current situation, modulo any hypothesis about God or other designers. Then, the answer to your question is easily obtained by an answer to the following: are you a linguist or a philosopher?

In your example:
Qua linguist, I observe the natural phenomena of intraspecies communication, further I observe that such communication is rich enough so as to display conventionality, creativity, etc. I then conclude - just as a linguist might do- what certain things mean based on behaviors, grammatical structure, and so forth ( I am not a linguist).

Qua philosopher, the matter is perhaps a little trickier. It will of course depend on one's foundational theory of meaning, as noted above, Quine might say that meaning is underdetermined here. But perhaps no more underdetermined then everyday communication is, which may or may not be favorable to you.

Comment: I like the bifurcation you offer as a summary of the problem of explicating the challenge of articulating a consistent position on fabilism; if text is so completely incomprehsible, why so useful?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm not sure why you introduce these "artificial" agents and then retract the idea that there is any human input. Human input is their environment. Why not just ask the same about ants or bacteria, where we do have responsive examples with no human input?

In any case, the taxis response function is compatible with both simple organisms and mechanisms and I don't think anyone would call it intelligent. But the food sharing leapfrogs a big threshold, the uniquely human capacity to "truck, barter, and trade," as Smith put it, and certainly implies intentionality, recognition, even a moral framework.

Several people have mentioned Quine, and his arguments would say, no, we can't tell what these entities are saying or "mean," since the possible contexts are infinitely divisible. We could observe the probabilities and impute intentions to them with shorthand phrases like "it wants..." But this is not to say the entities could do likewise.

You jump to yet another level when you talk about the possibility of lying. There would be no way to know, and we are now in pretty exclusively human territory, full self-consciousness and recognition. Yet if they algorithmically replicate such a trait, I suppose they would just end up extinct through their multiplying violation of Kant's rational categorial imperative.

There is also a lot we don't know about memory capacity, sensations, inheritance, signal errors, predatory co-evolution, and so forth. So I don't think your present scenario works. It begins with a kind of "Game of Life" prototype and by time you get to lying you've loaded in a nearly complete anthropomorphic package. So, on the seventh day, you can rest.

Comment: Compared to ants or bacteria, artificial agents have the advantage that we can fully access and analyze the contents of their "minds"; we are not restricted to only studying their outward behavior. We can fully delve into the inner causes of that behavior.

Comment: (Also, deception has been observed between evolved or trained artificial agents, see https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10462-008-9080-7 or https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Designing-Deception-in-Adversarial-Reinforcement-Choudhury-Deb/b6bd550d5e8859e34fa55460d32015e9847c22e5?p2df )